# Navigation drawer causing class not found exception even though support classes were imported

Tags: java, android

am getting this exception even though I imported the support jar

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
08-23 11:21:35.645: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-23 11:21:35.645: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-23 11:21:35.645: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-23 11:21:35.645: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
08-23 11:21:35.645: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project->AndroidTools->add support library
do this work twice,it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

the support jar was not being exported with the APKfile. so I checked them in build and export tab